# useNavigate not working react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router-dom v6 and I'm accessing the `from` value from the `location` object and it gives the `pathname` but when executing **navigate(from,{replace:true})** it does not work.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const { state } = useLocation();
const from = state ? state.from.pathname : '/';
const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isDone) {
      navigate(from, { replace: true }); //not working
    }
  }, [isDone]);
```

```
const Submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = { email, password };

    if (!email || !password) {
      setMessage('Please Enter All Fields');
    } else {
      setLoading(true);
      return await axios
        .post('/signin', data)
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.data.message === 'Invalid Credentials') {
            setMessage('Invalid Credentials');
          }
          if (res.data.message === 'Logged In') {
            setIsDone(true);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what "does not work" means. Is it navigating but not replacing? Or not navigating at all? Are there any console errors or React warnings?

Comment: @DBS not navigating and no warnings and errors

Comment: Have you tried putting something like `console.log(from)` on the line above your `navigate()` to make sure everything's as-expected at that point?

Comment: I tried that and I got the pathname

Comment: @HareePrasad I think from URL is the same as the current URL, that's why it's not redirecting.

Comment: @RahulSharma nope it is different, from url is '/cart' and the current url is '/signin' after login i'm navigating to cart page or if it doesn't have pathname it will navigate to home page.

Comment: @HareePrasad can you share the routing file also.

Comment: @RahulSharma https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-wood-pdjqs?file=/src/Signinin.js

Comment: Your codesandbox appears to be incomplete. Please update it so it runs and also provide a set of reproduction steps necessary to reproduce the issue in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing your CSB I see the redirect working. The issue is that the `auth` value in `App` doesn't change because your login flow doesn't set the `logged_in_status` value stored in localStorage. The result is that the user is bounced right back to the `"/signin"` route.

You should also be serializing/deserializing the data you save/access to/from localStorage.

App

```
const auth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('logged_in_status'));

...

useEffect(() => {
  const checkAuthStatus = async () => {
    return await axios.get("/loginstatus").then((res) => {
      if (res.data.message === "No Token") {
        localStorage.setItem("logged_in_status", JSON.stringify(false));
      }
      if (res.data.message === "Invalid Token") {
        localStorage.setItem("logged_in_status", JSON.stringify(false));
      }
      if (res.data.message === "Valid Token") {
        localStorage.setItem("logged_in_status", JSON.stringify(true));
      }
    });
  };
  checkAuthStatus();
});
```

Use a boolean expression for checking the `auth` value in your route wrappers.

```
const PublicRoute = () => {
  if (auth) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace={true} state={{ from: location }} />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
};

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  if (!auth) {
    return (
      <Navigate to="/signin" replace={true} state={{ from: location }} />
    );
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

Signin

Here you just need to set a `true` `"logged_in_status"` into localStorage upon successful authentication. There's also no real need I see for setting the `done` state; you can simply issue the imperative redirect when authenticated.

```
const Submit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = { email, password };

  if (!email || !password) {
    setMessage("Please Enter All Fields");
  } else {
    setLoading(true);
    return await axios
      .post("/signin", data)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.message === "Invalid Credentials") {
          setMessage("Invalid Credentials");
        }
        if (res.data.message === "Logged In") {
          localStorage.setItem("logged_in_status", JSON.stringify(true)); // <-- set localStorage
          navigate(from, { replace: true }); // <-- redirect
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }
};
```

[image: Edit usenavigate-not-working-react-router-dom-v6]

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with '/', remove it from the URL and try.

```
navigate(from.replace('/', '') , { replace: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

I just simply use:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
...
const navigate = useNavigate();
...
<Button onClick={() => navigate('../login', { replace: true })}>LogOut</Button>
```

So, I added `../` before the route and the `replace: true`.

Reference:- [React Router v6...](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigate)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
return <Navigate to={from} replace />
```

Answer (score -1):

in my case navigate is not work in Link tag

```
<Link onClick={()=>{navigate("/login")}}>
  <i className="fa fa-user-o  login-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</Link>
```

this is work for me.

```
<span onClick={()=>{navigate("/login")}}>
  <i className="fa fa-user-o  login-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: thats because the correct usage is <Link to="/login">

Comment: Thank you about checking my mistake. @MichaelTaylor3D